# Collapsible indented tree's initial state

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to make tree's **initial state** **folded** not spread, like below picture:

[image]

Not like this picture:

[image]

Which part should I fix? Should I fix the `update` function part? Or any other part? I can't reference my code because it is too long.

Reference : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't share **your** code, but just Bostock's one, this answer will be tailored to that bl.ocks.

What you want can be done changing the nodes at the first level, with:

```
root.children.forEach(function(d){
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
});
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/d6844f0377a2505c70a8b2ca1777cbac/3e9614786e1b2618408fca9674b0e20818c9b980